# Searching a value in a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have values in A1:A1000 and I have another column of values from B1:B500.

I want to check whether A1 is present in B1:B500; if it does I should get as PAID if it doesn't I should get NOT PAID. Similarly for A2,A3...... A1000.

I have used the following formulae but these don't work:

```
=IF(A2=(LOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$280)),"PAID","NOT PAID")
=IF((MATCH(A2,$B$2:$C$280, 0) "PAID","Not Paid")
=IF(A2=$C$2:$C$280,"Paid","Not Paid")
```

What am I doing wrong here? What's the correct formula?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) function, the syntax is as follows:

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

There are loads of examples, videos and good tutorials to be found here:

[VLOOKUP Function Examples And Videos](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions02.html)

Comment: I have tried this but it's not Working Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Just try below one

> =IF(ISNA(IF(A1=VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,0),"")),"Not Paid","Paid")

or

> =IF(ISNA(IF(A1=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$500,1,0),"")),"Not Paid","Paid")

Comment: It was showing too many arguments.Thankyou

Comment: Which version of MS office you are using, i mean 2007 or else..and did u try second formula which i mentioned

Comment: In 2010 I am using.YES both I tried I have done a small modification to your formula as "=(IF(A2=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$280,1,0),"paid","not paid"))", after doing this, theresult is not displaying instead of result only formula is displaying @cipher:Thankyou

Comment: When criteria doesnt match in vlookup it returns #N/A and "IF" condition doesnt know how to handle #N/A.so it ends in unexpected result like #N/A......so what i did is correct in my answer i handle that #N/A....and you're mention instead of result, formula is displaying.....so open a new excel by press Ctrl + N from old excel sheet and copy a empty cell and return to ur old excel and paste that blank cell where that problem occurs and then write formula again and do not copy and paste that old formula..because along with that formula, old cell formatting too paste in new cell.....